# Which is the supported version of rabitmq for magento 2.3 ce?

Tags: magento2.3, rabbit-mq

I followed the official magento documentation and installed Rabitmq 3.5.6.
However i was reading this document https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html
and i found that Rabitmq 3.5.6 version is older version and it is  strongly discourage to use it.
PlEASE GUIDE ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

> RabbitMQ 3.7.x (compatible with 2.0 and later)